# Adding xhr links to scraped categories hrefs missing scheme error

Tags: python-2.7, scrapy

i have built a spider which gets data from one category , the  method it follows is when the category page is specified in start url  and defining start_requests for pagination which iterates over the link provided by xhr request. Since i wanted to get all the categories at once i have written code like this. my logic was to first get all category links and append those links with xhr links which follows same string for every category which is (?from=24&ajax=true&search_query=&orderby=popular&orderway=asc&latestfilter=&source=menu) and parse these appended url to start_request and iterate them for pagination and item parsing . but i am not able to run spider because it throws the missing scheme error since in start request i havenot provided the http:// i am stuck onto how should i solve this issue please help..

```
class JabcatSpider(scrapy.Spider):
name = "jabcat"
allowed_domains = ["trendin.com"]
start_urls = [
'http://www.trendin.com',
]
max_pages = 400
def parse(self,response):
    urls =  response.xpath('//div[@class = "men"]//@href').extract()
    for url in urls:
        urljoin=(url + "/" "?from=24&ajax=true&search_query=&orderby=popular&orderway=asc&latestfilter=&source=menu")
        #yield scrapy.Request(urljoin, callback=self.start_requests)
        print urljoin

def start_requests(self):
    for i in range(self.max_pages):
         yield scrapy.Request('?from=%d&ajax=true&search_query=&orderby=popular&orderway=asc&latestfilter=&source=menu' % i, callback=self.parse)

def parse(self, response):
    for href in response.xpath('//*[@id="product_rows"]/div/div/div/a/@href'):
        url = response.urljoin(href.extract())
        yield scrapy.Request(url, callback=self.parse_detail_page)



def parse_detail_page(self, response):

    for sel in response.xpath('//*[@id="catalog-product"]/section[2]'):
        item = Jabongo()
        item['title'] = response.xpath('//*[@id="product-details-wrapper"]/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[1]/h1/span[2]/text()').extract()
#       item['price'] = response.xpath('//*[@id="pdp-price-info"]/span[2]/text()').extract()
#       item['image'] = response.xpath('//*[@class="content"]/h1/span[2]/text()').extract()
  #     # item['color'] = sel.xpath('//ul/li/label[.="Color"]/following-sibling::Span/text()').extract()
#   return item
     #pattern = response.xpath('//*[@class="content"]/h1/span[2]/text()').extract
```

Comment: @eLRuLL what I am doing is in first response I am joining the category url I scraped and the xhr request I get when I click on load more button for pagination . then using callback passing this modified url to start_request function where I want the response to be in for loop for the ?form = %d but i am stuck here I don't know how iterate the response I got from parse function in this function

Comment: @eLRuLL to better state my problem from the first parse function i am extracting category urls like eg:http://www.trendin.com/watches-451?source=menu .. this particular category has load more button which when clicked generates xhr request like this http://www.trendin.com/watches-451?from=24&ajax=true&search_query=&
orderby=popular&orderway=asc&latestfilter=&source=menu the part from=24 is common for all categories , so i decided to join that part using url join for all categories and call back start request to iterate the from = %d part but how do i do that ?

Comment: just string operations.

Comment: @eLRuLL can you give me an example code to follow i am quite new to scrapy

Comment: not a scrapy problem, send a correct and complete url to the Request

Comment: @eLRuLL is my code wrong if it is can you correct me on how can I achieve what I want

Comment: In `start_requests` the URL you pass to `Request()` is missing the domain. Try scraping the links on the home page to get your category pages.

Comment: @Steve if you see my code I am scraping the category url and joining it with the string I need for pagination and passing this modified url to start_request where I want to write logic to iterate the from= but I cannot figure out how to do it

Comment: `start_requests` runs before any scraping gets done. The `Request` call in that constructs a URL without the website's domain address hence the scheme error. Either construct the URL into a string and print it out so we can see what URL you are passing or comment out the `start_requests()` altogether and follow links from the home page using the `parse` routine.

Comment: I want the start requests to be dynamic is there a way I can join the category urls I scraped and the link I mentioned in start request. if I am giving one category in start request like this http:\\www.trendin.com\jeans\'?from=%d&ajax=true&search_query=&orderby=popular&orderway=asc&latestfilter=&source=menu' it's working . what I am trying to achieve is for different categories I want to append string which is ?from=%d and iterate in start request how can I do this?